# Ordering using stl sort in Visual Studio and GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, g++

Writing a program that should be portable in Linux and Windows enviroments I have found a issue with the STL sort function, when compiling with Visual studio and gcc.
In order to sort a vector of complex data structures I have written an int conversion operator for the structures in that form:

```
struct result
{ 
public :
  int Gene_a;
  int Gene_b;
  std::vector<int> score;
  float total_score;
  operator int() {return total_score;}
}
```

In that case I have no problem in visual studio using the standard sort algorithm for integers:

```
sort(results.rbegin(),results.rend());
```

But when trying to compile that using GCC ( actually g++ ) that lead to funny errors.
To avoid that seems that I have to write an ordering function:

```
 inline bool better (result a, result b)
 {
   return a.total_score > b.total_score;
 }
```

and invoke sort in the form:

```
sort(results.begin(),results.end(),better);
```

Was I using something out of the standard C++ or is a lack of the g++ STL implementation ?
Is it possible to let g++ understand that the vector of struct is equivalent to a vector of int ?

Here is a short main to illustrate the error:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  vector<result> r;           // define a vector of struct
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)      // fill up with data
  {
    result a;
    a.Gene_a=i;
    a.Gene_b=2*i;
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
      a.score.push_back(i); // fill the int vector in the struct
    a.total_score=i;
    r.push_back(a);
  }
  // sort(r.rbegin(),r.rend()); // this line will fail in g++
  sort(r.rbegin(),r.rend(),better);
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)      // demonstrate that the int operator works
    cout << (int)r[i] << endl;
}// End main
```

Comment: What version of g++?  What are the funny errors?  Can you come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the errors?  g++ 4.5.1 accepts the following without complaint: `struct X { operator int() const { return 42; } }; int main() { std::vector<X> v; std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); }`

Comment: g++ version was 4.6.1  The structure was:
`struct result
{ 
public :
int Gene_a;
int Gene_b;
std::vector<int> score;
float total_score;
operator int() {return total_score;}}`

At compile time that was giving me a lot of errors. If you really need I can try to make a screen dump for you.

Comment: Why would you make a screen dump?  Edit your question and copy-and-paste the code and the error messages into the text of the question.

Comment: Errors where to long ( screen of strings ) but I will put the code in the question.

Comment: @GBBL BTW you don't need `public:` in a `struct`.

Comment: yes.... all members are public in a struct but that should not a problem....

Comment: Please copy and paste the compile errors you have. If possible, give us a full but minimal source code listing that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @GBBL: Using a function is the way to go here. An implicit conversion can have many unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only meaningful difference I see between the two comparison methods is that the second will work when the element is `const`. The first should probably be:

```
//             vvvvv
operator int() const
```

Even though you're modifying the container, your comparison still has the requirement that it work on `const` objects. In your case, the implementation used that assumption and the error arose.

<strike>But this shouldn't matter, since to sort the container and its elements needs to be modifiable...</strike>

Comment: But when elements are compared, they shouldn't be modified, so the implementation may be right to enforce this. (The error occurs in `‘const _Tp& std::__median(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = result]’`)

Comment: @visitor: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I just wasn't sure if the implementation is allowed to assume, in a mutating algorithm, that the elements may be treated as const. Either way, the `const` is the culprit. I'm going to trust GCC on this one. Thanks.

Comment: @GBBL: *What* error? You need to copy and paste the error messages, they tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: OK I HAVE DONE A FINAL CHECK NOW ! In fact using the the const the error disappears ! Tried on Linux, MacOsX and... Windows with MiniGW. Thank to GMan and all others !